# Binding text with viewbox produces unwanted behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf

The appeareance of my button is perfect if I define what the text is.

Working Image

[image: Picture]

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Icons.Person}" Style="{StaticResource Icon}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="PERSONS"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I want to set the text to be Binding to a variable but this Overlaps the image.

Appearance after Bindings

[image: Binding Image]

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Icons.Person}" Style="{StaticResource Icon}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Persons"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Icon.xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Icons.Person">
    <Viewbox>
        <Path ......./>
    </Viewbox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Path code is huge, if it's needed I'll upload it.

What I've tried is changing the Datatemplate to be only a ViewBox with a key, and change content control to be a stackpanel with a viewbox within it and the text box. Same effect would happen. May I ask how to fix this or what's an alternative to show my datatemplate/viewbox with a binding text field

Comment: Something seems up with styling.  Why would the text color change when switching to a binding?  I've never had that happen in my WPF applications.  I'd go hunting with XAMLSpy to see the styles being applied to it.

Comment: You're missing a closing brace where you've written `="{Binding Persons"`

Comment: @Josh Yeah it has been puzzling me also :s